# get maximum value from database and set into jtextfield

Tags: java, swing, jdbc

I want to get maximum value from database (bill_number) and set into set into jtextfield. but I get error (void type not allowed here).

where is problem in my code

```
public void number(){
try{
   Class.forName("sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcDriver");
   Connection cn = DriverManager.getConnection("Jdbc:Odbc:ds_comboPractice");
   String sql = "select count(Bill_Number)=? from combopractice";
   PreparedStatement pst = cn.prepareStatement(sql);
   pst.setString(1, txt4.setText(sql));
   pst.executeQuery();
   cn.close();

}
catch(ClassNotFoundException ex){
   JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this, "Class not found");
   }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to do `txt4.getText` not `setText`

You then want to assign the results of your `executeQuery` to a `ResultSet` and read the result from that.

Answer (score 0):

```
pst.setString(1, txt4.setText(sql));
```

`setText()` returns `void`

You need a String argument